AUTOSAR NM and XCP PDUs doesn't have PDU Triggering, why?
I see the following AUTOSAR snippet which mentions that NM and XCP PDU doesn't have PDU Triggering.
Can you please provide me some rationale for this statement as well as corresponding description with AUTOSAR which specifies any statement equivalent to this snippet as highlighted?


The reason for this modelling approach is documented in the specification item TPS_SYST_01052.
